# 18.04 - Disk says "read only", and then reboot goes into initramfs

Tags: 18.04, initramfs

I was trying to work on some files on my Ubuntu machine, and when I tried to save them, it told me that the disk was read only. I then rebooted the machine, but upon rebooting into Ubuntu it displayed an `initramfs` command prompt with all my files gone. How do I restore my desktop environment and my files?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  This advice is general only, but if your file-system went RO (read-only) it was probably because an error was detected, I would have investigated before you shutdown, but the result is probably the same. I'd boot a 'live' system (eg. install media) and `fsck` (do a file system check) of your system. The command needed may not be `fsck`, but may be `xfs_check`  so I'm speaking generally (adjust for your chosen file-system).  ps: if it was a file system error, once fixed, you can reboot & login normally.

Comment: @guiverc fyi: please see my answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a disk error(s) caused your disk to become ro.

**First, lets check out the file system...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Then lets check the SMART Data...**

- open the `Disks` application
- select `SMART Data & Tests` from the hamburger icon
- review the data, looking for parameters with "sector" in the name
- take a screenshot and edit it into your question
- run the SMART Tests

Comment: Running the first part and using `fsck` fixed everything for me. Thank you!

Comment: @xXGETREKTXx glad it's working for you now!